# What is the right approach for getting a simple count value using ZF2 database queries?

Tags: orm, zend-framework2, zend-db

All I want is the number of records matching a criteria (there's other places where I want more information from the table, and the model/gateway has methods to do this - but all I want is the number).

Using Zend Framework 2, I only see two options, and I don't quite find either of them a palatable solution:

One - do a simple SELECT - and we have upto 50,000 or more records each day.

```
$select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();

$select->columns(array(
    "hits" => "id",
));

$select->where->between("timestamp", $start, $end);

$results = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);

return $results->count();
```

Two - do a SELECT COUNT() - and then have to iterate the resultset once and access via the model.

```
$select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();

$select->columns(array(
    "hits" => new Expression("COUNT(timestamp)"),
));

$select->where->between("timestamp", $start, $end);

$results = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);

foreach ($results as $result) {
    return $result->hits;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more thought, and doing a similar query but with additional information:

```
$select->columns(array(
        "searches"    => new Expression("COUNT(time)"),
        "successes"   => new Expression("COUNT(IF(hits > 0, 1, NULL))"),
        "failures"    => new Expression("COUNT(IF(hits = 0, 1, NULL))"),
        "suggestions" => new Expression("COUNT(IF(suggestions > 0, 1, NULL))")
    ));
```

I've figured that it would be best to return the first model in the resultset, simply for consistency in how the information is structured from these queries.

Although, I'm still not 100% on this approach.